# Is there a way to create a shortcut or alias for git option(s)

Tags: git, git-alias

I find myself using `--name-status` option a lot with `git log`, `git diff`, `git show`. I'm aware of git aliases but they only work for a command or a combination of command and/or option(s). I **do not** want to create git aliases just for this option.

```
# l is an alias for log with pretty format
git l --name-status
```

So I can do something like this where `--ns` is shortcut for `--name-status`:

```
git l --ns
```

---

**Update**: See [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42056579/58678) for the different considerations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barring modifying the source code to recognize additional flags, your best bet is probably using aliases to rewrite the flag:

```
[alias]
    l = "!l() { : git log ; git log $(echo \"$@\" | sed \"s/--ns/--name-status/\") ; } && l"
```

Alternatively you can define some alias `g` in bash that will do this for you (you can configure auto-complete to work with this but I don't remember how to do that off the top of my head):

```
function g {
    git $(echo "$@" | sed "s/--ns/--name-status/")
}
```

Comment: "I do not want to create git aliases just for this option."

Comment: This helped me come up with my solution so marking it as answer.

Comment: Happy to help! JW - what did you end up going with, so people who see this in the future know?

Comment: @Pockets, I had posted my answer below and updated the question (see below). I take care of a corner case where I replace the exact option. This is an issue for `--no` (`--name-only`) as there is already a `--no-prefix` switch for `diff`.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this **hack** is helpful to someone so posting it here. It's based on [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42011671/58678) to this question.

I could have created my own git commands `~/bin/git-<custom command>` but preferred to change my existing git aliases as I backup my `.gitconfig`. git commands have the advantage of executing in the current directory when `<path>` is mentioned (no need for `cd ${GIT_PREFIX:-.}` mentioned below).

I pulled out the replace options logic into a helper fn `options`. It's then used for aliases `l` (`log`), `d` (`diff`), `dt` (`difftool`), etc. I intentionally kept that fn in `gitconfig` rather than a shell script so everything is in one place. It's easy to add new options to that fn too.

`cd ${GIT_PREFIX:-.}` is required to honor `<path>` for git aliases that execute as shell commands ([see this](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-alias)). This is important for `git log`.

> Note that shell commands will be executed from the top-level directory
>   of a repository, which may not necessarily be the current directory.

I already had aliases for `log`, `diff`, `difftool`. It is not possible to have a git alias or custom git command to override a built-in git command and did not want to create one for `show` so I left out `git show`.

**Before:**

```
[alias]
    l       = !"cd ${GIT_PREFIX:-.} && git lg2"
    d       = diff
    dt      = difftool
    lg2     = # alias for log
```

**After:**

```
[alias]
    l       = "!f() { cd ${GIT_PREFIX:-.} && git lg2 $(git options "$@"); }; f"
    d       = "!f() { cd ${GIT_PREFIX:-.} && git diff $(git options "$@"); }; f"
    dt      = "!f() { cd ${GIT_PREFIX:-.} && git difftool $(git options "$@"); }; f"
    lg2     = # alias for log
    #workaround: helper fn to alias options
    options = "!f() { \
                echo "$@" \
                    | sed 's/\\s/\\n/g' \
                    | sed 's/^--ns$/--name-status/' \
                    | sed 's/^--no$/--name-only/' \
                    | xargs; \
            }; f"
```

So now I can do:

```
git l --ns
git d head~ --ns
git dt head~ --ns

# with paths:
git l --ns -- <path>
git d head~ --ns -- <path>
git dt head~ --ns -- <path>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think aliasing command line arguments is possible.